# Error while importing SBT project in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /Users/usernew/.sbt/0.13/plugins
**java.io.IOException: Permission denied**
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
at scala.reflect.io.AbstractFile.fileOrSubdirectoryNamed(AbstractFile.scala:235)
at scala.reflect.io.AbstractFile.fileNamed(AbstractFile.scala:246)
```

I am getting this error locally

Comment: [info] Loading global plugins from /Users/user/.sbt/0.13/plugins
**java.io.IOException: Permission denied**
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
at scala.reflect.io.AbstractFile.fileOrSubdirectoryNamed(AbstractFile.scala:235)
at scala.reflect.io.AbstractFile.fileNamed(AbstractFile.scala:246)
at scala.tools.nsc.backend.jvm.BytecodeWriters$class.getFile(BytecodeWriters.scala:3

Comment: do you have permission to import at destination directory?

Comment: Are you on Windows? Do you have (part of) that project opened in another program?